# flash is not playing in android 2.2 and also not able to run flash file?

Tags: android, flash, adobe

hello i want to play a flash file which is in sd card on my android
      device for that i installed flash player and when i am runnning my
      program iit is showing blank white screen but if i click  on flask
      .swf file in sd card than it shows that application not  available.
       please tell me what is the problem and also tell  me which software should install in device to run the flash in application.
              i already install adoble flash player and air also in my android device but after that also i am not able to see the
 flash in
      my android device and if i am directly clicking on the flash .swf file
      it display a toast message that application not available

> ```
> enter code here
> ```
>
> try {
>
> ```
>       // html file with sample swf video in sdcard
>
>       //flash.html points to swf in sdcard
>
>       mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
>       mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
>       mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
>       mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
> ```
>
> if
>   (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
>                 System.exit(4);      } else {        String url ="file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/LOST.DIR/"+"p.swf"+"";
>
> ```
>        mWebView.loadUrl(url);      }
>
>   }
>   catch (Exception e) {           // TODO: handle exception
>       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), 1).show();        }
> ```

Comment: i already installed adobe flash player and adobe air on my android device